# How to run rabbitmqctl commands using python subprocess?

Tags: python, rabbitmqctl

Running `rabbitmqctl` from a Python package using subprocess returns "command not found".

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/rabbitmqctl', 'arguments'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0]
rt = proc.returncode
```

The above code is part of a python project that will be packaged to a wheel distribution. After installing the wheel through pip, the above code returns an exit code 127 which is "command not found".

I tried with the full path to rabbitmqctl, used sudo with the command, used preexec_fn in subprocess and set the uid to rabbitmq user but everything returns returncode 127.

The command executes fine in the python interpreter. Issue is only when the code is installed as a package.

This code is part of a flask app which is controlled by gunicorn. I've even tried to start gunicorn with sudo, but ended up getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the python virtual environment.

I installed the package that has the rabbitmqctl command in a python virtual environment. So even though the module had root privileges, it is not able to find rabbitmqctl command because the path to that binary was not part of the PATH environment variable of the virtual environment. I fixed it by adding the env parameter in subprocess.

```
rabbit_env = os.environ.copy()
rabbit_env['PATH'] = '/path/where/rabbitmqctl/is/located/:' + rabbit_env['PATH']
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/rabbitmqctl', 'arguments'], env=rabbit_env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0]
rt = proc.returncode
```

The reason why I got exit code 127 even when I specified the full path of rabbitmqctl is because rabbitmqctl is a script that runs some other commands and rabbitmqctl was not able to find those dependent commands in the PATH because those commands' locations are not part of the virtual environment PATH. So make sure you add the locations of all the rabbitmqctl dependent commands in the rabbit_env['PATH'] above.